# coloring buttons

Tags: java, swing

i want to color the text inside the button 
how can i do that?
i made that code:

```
for(int i=0; i<10 ;i++)
    {
        arr[i]=new Button(""+i);
        arr[i].
        arr[i].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        p1.add(arr[i]);
        this.arr[i].addActionListener(this);
    }
```

the buttons text color is black. 
if i want to color the text in the button from black to blue what i need to write?

Answer (score 4):

arr[ i ].setForeground( Color.BLUE );

Answer (score 1):

Wrap up the text for every button in HTML. For example,

```
JButton button = new new JButton("<html><font color=#ffffdd>Caption</font></html>");
```

More information can be found [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html).

Comment: Setting the foreground is a simpler option.

Comment: @jzd Agree -- simpler, but with HTML one has more flexibility in styling the text (button captions, labels etc.). Hence, the suggestion.